# Alter taxonomy autocomplete value

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, forms

I need to alter the element value of a taxonomy autocomplete field before it is processed and can't seem to find a way of doing so.

taxonomy autocomplete fields have an [element validator](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#element_validate) attached, that replaces the String value with an array of terms:

```
[$form] (array)
  [field_myautocomplete] (array)
    [und] (array)
      [#element_validate] (array)
        [0] => "taxonomy_autocomplete_validate" (string)
```

I need to alter the String before the validator `taxonomy_autocomplete_validate() // taxonomy.module:1747` passes it to `drupal_explode_tags() // common.inc:7416`. Thus I attach my own element validator via `hook_form_alter()`:

```
[$form] (array)
  [field_myautocomplete] (array)
    [und] (array)
      [#element_validate] (array)
        [0] => "MYMODULE_validate" (string)
        [1] => "taxonomy_autocomplete_validate" (string)
```

My validator is executed first and uses `form_set_value()` to update the value (exactly what `taxonomy.module:1782` does in its validator).

However, this only updates the value for `$form_state` and not `$element` which is the value used by `taxonomy_autocomplete_validate()`. Thus, the altered value is completely ignored and gets overwritten by the second validator, based on the original string.

Any suggestions beyond hacking core (make `taxonomy_autocomplete_validate` use `$form_state`) are most welcome.

Comment: I guess I could remove the core validator entirely and implement a copy myself that honors $form_state - not very DRY though.

Answer (score 1):

the simple solution to this issue, is to pass $element by reference to the first element validator:

```
function MYMODULE_validate(&$element, &$form_state) {
  (...)
  form_set_value($element, $new_value, $form_state);
  $element['#value'] = 'new_value';
}
```

This way, the $element['#value'] (used by the taxonomy_autocomplete_validate) can be modified and the following validators will.

The form_set_value() is not required, but since the form value has changed, it makes sense to update the state as well.

* *many thanks to @ciss for helping troubleshoot the issue on #drupal and suggesting the pass by reference.*